# Laravel slow simple query with Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with a query with laravel, I have a database with 250k records called orders

When I try to get a paginated orders by client_id, I get 504 time out.

The query is very simple.

```
$ordenes = Order::where('client_id', $id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

My temporary solution was increment from 1gb RAM to 2gb and 1cpu to 2cpu's. But I want to know if it's posible optimize this simple query to get a faster response.

Comment: are both `client_id` and `id` indexed fields? if not, try to add an index to them

Comment: orderBy will index your entire table so the pagination is almost pointless as you are loading everything.

Comment: I added index for client_id and I don't see any difference. And it's true, without orderBy is more faster the response, but, how can I order my data without orderBy?

Comment: Show us the generated SQL; we can approach the question from that side.  (The "natural" way to do pagination is terribly inefficient.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have another related table, eloquent is a little more slow than query builder, but not so much.

Comment: Yes, I made some test with query builder and when I trying to get data invoices is slow again. I came just to say this, and I see your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

by my little expirience, you should index client_id and ID. Next, consider using datatables, with server side loading, this will drastically increase performance and adds search functionality. Last, use query builder. Eloquent is really, really heavy in your case.

Could not answer the POST since I upvote the Fabiotk's comment.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I tried with query builder, and the difference is impressive, thanks a lot. Maybe with the index added, works better.

Comment: Eloquent os really powerfull, but with a cost. Do indexes, will improve de speed. Btw you can test it with debugbsr package. Regards